# What does "lift the under" mean?

Tags: meaning

> When compared to the current domestic spending through the market of around
>   $70 million, the expanded spending of some $137 million is a considerable boost.
>   Subscriptions as well as transaction fees would considerably **lift the under** $1
>   million commission received since the 2002 Post buyout of the cartel.

What does "lift the under" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read it as **lift the under-one-million-dollar commission**.

That is, **under** is modifying **$1 million**. Another way to say it is:

> Subscriptions as well as transaction fees would considerably **lift** the commission. The commission received since the 2002 Post buyout of the cartel is currently **under** $1 million.

Answer (score 1):

> Subscriptions as well as transaction fees would considerably lift the under $1 million commission received since the 2002 Post buyout of the cartel

Written another way:

> Having received under $1 million in commission since the 2002 Post buyout of the cartel, the commission could be considerably lifted by subscriptions and transaction fees.

"the under $1 million commission" is one single entity.